# Colors and bold text

Tags: python

So i know there is a bold text question up and I got this from it. I'm trying to make single letters bold whilst the others normal. So heres my attempt. I took this and input it into my code:

```
class color:
   PURPLE = '\033[95m'
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   DARKCYAN = '\033[36m'
   BLUE = '\033[94m'
   GREEN = '\033[92m'
   YELLOW = '\033[93m'
   RED = '\033[91m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'
```

This is where i try to input the colors BOLD.

```
selection= input('Do you wish to view the results in Alphabetical order 'color.BOLD + '(A)' + color.END',\n scores highest to lowest'color.BOLD + '(B)' + color.END',\n or average score highest to lowest?'color.BOLD + '(C)' + color.END)
```

However I get a syntax error saying Invalid Syntax.

Comment: Not sure why I got down-voted..

Comment: It might be because it matches rule two for [off-topic questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, these are often resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a `SyntaxError` because your syntax is invalid. You are missing a plus sign before `color.BOLD` and after `color.END`.

```
selection= input('Do you wish to view the results in Alphabetical order ' + color.BOLD + '(A)' + color.END + ',\n scores highest to lowest' + color.BOLD + '(B)' + color.END + ',\n or average score highest to lowest?' + color.BOLD + '(C)' + color.END)
```

Comment: Windows doesn't support that. Try something like [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) for support.